# Create multidimensional array from rows

Tags: php, arrays

The result of a query in my database returns something like this (a record for each row):

```
1.
1.1.
1.1.01.
1.1.01.001
1.2.
1.2.01.
1.2.02.
```

I'm trying to create something that returns me a multidimensional array in a tree format, like this:

```
array(
    '1.' => array(
        '1.1' => array(
            '1.1.01.' => array(
                (int) 0 => '1.1.01.001'
            )
        ),
        '1.2' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1.2.01.',
            (int) 1 => '1.2.02.'
        )
    )
)
```

All I could think to do was reverse the order of elements using `explode()`.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You'll get your result in an array. Take that array and loop through it and switch places/create new arrays inside it.

Comment: What is wrong with the reverse the order of elements using `explode` ??? seems to work

Comment: I think this answer would help you: [Create Multidimensional array from text lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642688/create-multidimensional-array-from-text-lines)

Comment: @GeorgeViolaris its totally different .. not the final value has combination of all the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is very tricky because of :

```
1.2.
1.2.01.     |
1.2.02.     V  Making this array instead of value
```

You can try

```
$string = "1.
1.1.
1.1.01.
1.1.01.001
1.2.
1.2.01.
1.2.02.";

$array = explode("\n", $string);
$data = array();
$temp = &$data;

$it = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE);
$continue = false;
foreach ( $it as $v ) {
    $v = trim($v);
    if ($it->hasNext()) {
        $next = trim($it->getInnerIterator()->current());
        if (stripos($next, $v) === 0) {
            $temp = &$temp[$v];
        } else {
            $temp[] = $v;
            if (strlen($next) != strlen($v)) {
                $temp = &$data;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $temp[] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1.] => Array
        (
            [1.1.] => Array
                (
                    [1.1.01.] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1.1.01.001
                        )

                )

        )

    [1.2.] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.2.01.
            [1] => 1.2.02.
        )

)
```

[Here is a move COMPLEX demo](http://eval.in/11165)

Comment: Almost, because item `1.2` need to stay at the same level of `1.1`. Item 1 has 1.1 and 1.2, item 1.1 has 1.1.01 and so on. I'll try to modify your solution, thanks anyway.